# extract [+-] decimals from a text using jquery regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to extract the positive and negative decimals from a text using `jquery-regex`.

For example:

Text = -1r2XXX.0abc23

Result= -12.023

the following code is extracting only the positive decimals, how to extract the negative decimals also.

Text = -1r2XXX.0abc23

Result= 12.023 // (-) is missing

```js
var original_text="-1r2XXX.0abc23";
var extracted_text = original_text.replace(/^\.|[^\d\.]|\.(?=.*\.)|^0+(?=\d)/g, '');
console.log(extracted_text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

In regex if you want to check the beginning of a text you have to use: ^ then the value

Now if this value is optional then you have to end it with:?

So your regex should be: ^-?

**Solution:**

Full code

```js
var original_text="-12XXX.0abc23";
var extracted_text = original_text.replace(/^\.|[^-?\d\.]|\.(?=.*\.)|^0+(?=\d)/g, '');
console.log(extracted_text);
```